# Jackson ignores JsonProperty annotation in deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I've got a bit of a conundrum.  I'm trying to deserialize a json message into a pojo using the builder pattern and I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Information" 
(class com.verification.client.models.response.Response$Builder), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "status", "products", "information"])
```

This is very confusing to me as I've clearly marked the field in the pojo with a JsonProperty annotation:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Response.Builder.class)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Response {
    @JsonProperty("Status")
    private final Optional<Status> status;
    @JsonProperty("Products")
    private final Optional<List<ResponseProduct>> products;
    @JsonProperty("Information")  //Here's where the field is defined
    private final Optional<List<ResponseInformation>> information;

    private Response(final Builder b){
        this.status = b.status;
        this.products = b.products;
        this.information = b.information;
    }

    public Optional<Status> getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Optional<List<ResponseProduct>> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public Optional<List<ResponseInformation>> getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder{
        private Optional<Status> status;
        private Optional<List<ResponseProduct>> products = Optional.empty();
        private Optional<List<ResponseInformation>> information = Optional.empty();

        public Builder(){}

        public Builder status(final Status status){
            this.status = Optional.of(status);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder products(final List<ResponseProduct> products){
            this.products = Optional.of(products);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder information(final List<ResponseInformation> information){
            this.information = Optional.of(information);
            return this;
        }

        public Response build(){
            return new Response(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling it's something small, but at this point I am at a loss for why my code is behaving this way.

P.S.
Here's the json I'm deserializing

```
{
"Information": [{
    "InformationType": "error-details",
    "Code": "internal_application_error",
    "Description": "Error: Internal",
    "DetailDescription": []
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this a while back, answering for posterity.

The issue I was having is that the build methods were not being correctly interpreted, but by defining @JsonSetter annotations on the methods of the static build class Jackson was able to correctly interpret the input and build the object.